# Rails js is not executed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In assets/javascripts/blog.js.coffee

```
console.log('123')
```

When page is loaded, this is in html (development mode):

```
<script src="/assets/blog.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Content of this file:

```
(function() {

  console.log('123');

}).call(this);
```

But when page is loaded browser console is empty, this means that js is not executed.

In what could be the problem? Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect invalid Coffeescript to produce expected results.

Rename your file to `assets/javascripts/blog.js` or change the content of the file to

```
(->
  console.log "123"
).call this
```

Comment: coffe script compiles to javascript, so any correct js is correct coffee.js as well, right?

Comment: I don't understand your logic, or how it applies here. A `.js.coffee` file in Rails is going to pass the file's contents through the CoffeeScript compiler. Passing **Javascript** through the **CoffeeScript** compiler does not produce valid **Javascript**. OP's code, for example, throws a `syntax error: reserved word 'function'` error. You need to escape raw Javascript embedded in CoffeeScript files **[with backticks](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded)**

Comment: thx I missed the part with backticks - your answer might be valid in that case